# How do I preprocess rows fetched with sqlx?

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

Consider the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Data struct {
    Stuff string
}

func main() {
    db, _ := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "root:root@(localhost:3306)/data")
    var datas []Data
    db.Select(&datas, "select 'a,b' stuff from data limit 10")
    fmt.Println(datas)
}
```

What I'd like to do is have `Stuff` as `[]string`, where it would be split by `,`. I guess I could add an extra `[]string` field and loop over the results populating this field and removing the source data, but that seems inefficient. What's the canonical way to do this in `sqlx`?

Comment: Offtopic: SQL tables and resultsets are **orderless** by definition without using `ORDER BY`.. Using `limit 10` to get the "first 10" records from the table is deterministic (random) these "first ten" records can be anny record from the table, something to be aware off here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not supported out of the box you can create custom struct implementing Scanner interface (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner):

```
type StringList []string

// Scan implements Scanner interface and parses 
// database result to StringList struct.
func (s *StringList) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var source string

    switch src.(type) {
    case string:
        source = src.(string)
    case []byte:
        source = string(src.([]byte))
    default:
        return errors.New("Incompatible type for StringList")
    }

    *s = strings.Split(source, ",")
    for i := range *s {
        (*s)[i] = strings.TrimSpace((*s)[i])
    }

    return nil
}
```

And use this struct instead of `string`:

```
type Data struct {
    Stuff StringList
}
```